# Where's my free space gone on my MP3 player?

Tags: disk-space, mp3

I have a Sansa Fuze MP3 player, it's 4 GB.

I plug it in my Mac I have a capacity of 3,7 GB of which apparently 1,8 GB is in use.

Problem is I only have arround 120 MB of MP3s on it...

Who's stealing my free space ?

Here are DiskInventoryX screenshots. I have the same results with du and the terminal.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok problem solved.

I repaired the disk using `Disk Utility.app`. Some blocks were not marked as free apparently!

Answer (score 1):

It might also be the trash -- I'm not sure how DiskInventoryX copes with trash directories on external drives. It might be worth emptying your trash while the drive is mounted.

Answer (score 0):

The missing space is probably the operating system and other hidden system files.